# How to use user defined metric in KernelDensity from scikit-learn (python)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, kernel-density, metric

I'm using scikit-learn (0.14) and trying to implement a user defined metric for my KernelDensity estimation.

Following code is an example how my code is structured:

```
def myDistance(x,y):
    return np.sqrt(sum((x - y)**2))

dt=DistanceMetric.get_metric("pyfunc",func=myDistance)

kernelModel=KernelDensity(algorithm='ball_tree',metric='pyfunc')
kernelModel.fit(X)
```

According to the documentation, the BallTree algorithm should accept user defined metrics.
If I run this code the way given here, I get following error:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 positional argument (0 given)
```

The error seems to come from:

```
sklearn.neighbors.dist_metrics.PyFuncDistance.__init__
```

I don't understand this. If i check what 'dt' in the code above gives me, I get what I expect. dt.pairwise(X) returns the correct values.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Solution is

```
kernelModel=KernelDensity(...,metric='pyfunc',metric_params={"func":myDistance})
```

The call to Distancemetric.get_metric is not necessary.
M